# packages installed via Software Center do not show up in menu without reboot

Tags: command-line, package-management, 16.04, software-center

After installing Opera using the Software Center, its icon does not show up in the start menu.

But after I reboot, it does show up in the start menu.

It's really annoying that I have to keep restarting the computer every time I install something, and I didn't need to restart after installing new software on Ubuntu 14.04. Is there any way I can fix this issue?

It seems when I install something using `apt-get` it shows up right away, but when I install something using the Software Center it requires a reboot before showing up.

How can I get programs installed from the Software Center to show up in the menu right away?

Comment: I think you should take a look at how to ask a question http://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: iv done it correctly.. iv been specifc , i have not been vague... sure i might have some spelling and grammer issues , but not everyone has perfect english.... i ask a question , then start geting messages about geting banned from asking questions...... what have i done wrong? do i have to have perfect spelling and english to ask for help?... iv tried researching the issue on google , nothing comes up that is usefull or helpfull , or at least none that i found...so how am i asking it wrong?

Comment: Hi Kenney: I've edited your question to hopefully make it more clear to people; I hope this helps

Comment: Thank you. now i hope i can get some help with this issue.

Comment: This crap has been going on for several LTS versions and it's annoying as hell. Makes me want to switch distros. What I do, if I don't wish to reboot, is find the program in the terminal by typing it's name, start it, then, when it appears in the launcher, right click offers "add to dash".

Comment: Im not that good with command line , could you provide an example please?

Comment: @KenneyOgden It's simple: Type `opera` for launching Opera, `firefox` for Firefox, etc.